# Adding a route for local network to bypass VPN doesn't work

Tags: subnet, route

I'm using a VPN which use [Bitmask](https://bitmask.net) to create the tunnel. I'd like to access my local network and hence added a route using `ip route add`:

```
ip route add 172.16.0.0/16 via 172.16.46.1
```

I got the the gateway by using `ip route show | grep default` which I found on another Stackexchange answer. However, this did not work. I specified the device as well but that didn't work either.

This is the output of `ip route show`

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.41.0.1 dev tun1 
default via 172.16.46.1 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp metric 20100 
10.41.0.0/21 dev tun1 proto kernel scope link src 10.41.0.89 
10.41.0.0/21 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.41.0.37 
37.218.241.7 via 172.16.46.1 dev enp3s0 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.41.0.1 dev tun1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp3s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.16.0.0/16 via 172.16.46.1 dev enp3s0 
172.16.46.0/23 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.46.104 metric 100 
198.252.153.28 via 172.16.46.1 dev enp3s0 
212.83.143.67 via 172.16.46.1 dev enp3s0
```

My route does seem to get added to the routing table. However, I still cannot access website in my local network, nor can I ping them. Doing a similiar thing (`route add 172.16.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 172.16.46.1`) on Windows works perfectly.

Does the order of the routes as outputted by `ip route show` affect the final route chose? The default route (0.0.0.0) is through the tun1, an interface created by the VPN software. Will that route be chosen first? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: "*However, I still cannot access website in my local network, nor can I ping them*" don't tell us, show us.

Comment: I'm not sure how to show you. I can't access any intranet websites (University captive portal).

Comment: Cut and paste.  Show us the commands you typed, and the output you got.  Imagine you're trying to *prove* your assertions to a colleague, instead of just stating "*I tested X and it failed.*".

Answer (score 0):

How to troubleshoot your issue in two steps:

1. Check the actual route to the ip address of the site with the `ip route get <dst-ip>`.
2. Run the `tcpdump -ni enp3s0 'ip host <site-ip>'` and check the traffic. When you run the ping you should see outgoing ICMP echo requests. If you see them, you should check the remote side - an issue somewhere else, not on your host. On the windows run the wireshark and then compare the results.

Comment: `172.16.0.30 via 172.16.95.129 dev enp3s0 src 172.16.95.195 uid 1000 
    cache`
This is what `ip route get 172.16.0.30` returns. I try to ping this server (after doing the tcpdump) and the error I get is 
`From 172.16.46.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Port Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Have you run the tcpdump? What have you seen in the output? As you can see the host `172.16.46.1` answers you with error. Check the firewall on that host.